# Disproving a claim regarding a linear transformation

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations, inner-products

I received the following claim:

Let $T:V \to V$ be a linear transformation and $U$ a subspace of  $V$. if $T(U) \subseteq U$, then $T(U^\bot) \subseteq U^\bot$.

I am having issues disproving the claim. I tried setting $T:R^2 \to R^2$ by $T(v)=proj_uv$ and
$U=span \lbrace \begin{bmatrix}1 \\0 \\\end{bmatrix} \rbrace $

Any assistance will be welcomed.

Comment: Please show us your work. As it stands this question should not be answered and in the worst case will have your account banned. Please have a look at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1

Comment: It it was true it would mean the representation of $T$ would be block diagonal.

Comment: try matrix $$ \left( \begin{array}{cc} 1&1 \\     0&1\end{array} \right)  $$ on $R^2$ where your $U$ is the x-axis, vectors with coordinates $$ \left( \begin{array}{c} x \\     0 \end{array} \right)  $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The claim is false without more restrictions.

As a counterexample let $T:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, such that $T(e1) = e1$ and $T(e2) = e1$. Suppose we have the usual inner product. Let $U = span<e_1>$. Then $U^{\perp} = span<e_2>$